# Firefox syntax error on Travis CI though Karma passes locally

Tags: javascript, webpack, karma-jasmine, travis-ci

### Problem:

I am getting the error saying `Syntax Error: let is a reserved identified`
But of course, when I look into the file at the stated lines, I don't see any `let` keywords (also because I used babel to transpile it too, see details below).

**Update**: The code around the source lines for [app.bundle.js, line 24](http://pastebin.com/tnU8GiwF) and [spec.bundle.js, line 12](http://pastebin.com/ZUtWvT5r).

[image: Travis build failed log]
**[Or view the full log here](http://pastebin.com/gUMrR1Y5)**

### What I'm using:

I am using Webpack, together with its babel-loader and babel-polyfill, to bundle my code because I want it transpiled from ES6 to ES5. [Here's my Webpack config](https://github.com/seckwei/SirKit_CircuitSim/blob/develop/webpack.config.js).

For Karma, I am running it with the karma-firefox-launcher. [Here's my Karma config](https://github.com/seckwei/SirKit_CircuitSim/blob/develop/karma.config.js).

Lastly, for Travis CI, I'm running with [this config](https://github.com/seckwei/SirKit_CircuitSim/blob/develop/.travis.yml).

### What I have done:

I have downloaded Firefox 31.0 (because in the log it said it ran FF31), then running karma with the command I have in .travis.yml - `karma start karma.config.js`. Firefox popped up as expected, the test ran, completed and passed.

I have Google'd, Stackoverflow'd, Github Issue'd but to avail. I would love to think that something is cached and hence not picking up the right version, but I have checked Travis options and it says I have nothing cached. Any ideas?

Any help or feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly does the code look like around the indicated source lines?

Comment: Thanks. Edited my question with the links. Under 'Problem' section. Not sure if its better to screenshot them or paste them in a bin but I hope they're good enough. Let me know if I'm missing any more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a back slash in your webpack configuration, which is correct only for windows:

```
test: /(js|spec)\\.+\.js$/,
```

this test will not match your source files paths, on unix systems(with forward slash in paths), as result - babel will not transpile anything

To support all systems, It should be changed to:

```
test: /(js|spec)(\/|\\).+\.js$/,
```

Comment: That's odd because I can see some transpiled code in my *.bundle.js even without your suggestion. I will give this a try and see. Cheers

Comment: Also just to mention since you have updated your answer: I have actually downloaded FF31, but since you said that, I have given a test with `let` in the console and it seems to work. :O Whaat? Help > About shows FF31, maybe I'm missing something here about the versions.

Comment: Are you using windows locally? Maybe, on windows your test expression would be valid because they are using backslashes in paths, So correct test for all platforms would be `/(js|spec)(\/|\\).+\.js$/,`

Comment: Yes, I am using windows. Perhaps that's why! Interestingly, when I switch between the forward and back slash, there seems to be some code changes as well (I know by comparing the total lines). I'll do a diff between the two and see what's up. Thanks!